Significant performance difference between `x += y` and `x = xLocal + y` where x is a property, with different results on different machines
I was running some field vs property benchmarks out of curiosity and ran into these notable results:
| Method                                | Runtime  | Mean       | Error   | StdDev  | Code Size |
|-------------------------------------- |--------- |-----------:|--------:|--------:|----------:|
| Property_ReadWrite_Write_Add          | .NET 7.0 | 1,352.2 ns | 5.95 ns | 5.57 ns |      33 B |
| Property_ReadWrite_Write_Add_Separate | .NET 7.0 |   186.9 ns | 0.53 ns | 0.50 ns |      33 B |
| Property_ReadWrite_Write_Add          | .NET 8.0 |   186.8 ns | 0.45 ns | 0.40 ns |      25 B |
| Property_ReadWrite_Write_Add_Separate | .NET 8.0 |   186.9 ns | 0.40 ns | 0.35 ns |      25 B |

Disassembly
The benchmarking code is visible in the following images (text version below), along with the disassembly:


.NET 7.0.15 (7.0.1523.57226), X64 RyuJIT AVX2
; Benchmarks.FieldVsProperty.Property_ReadWrite_Write_Add()
;         for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
;              ^^^^^^^^^
;             Prop_ReadWrite += i;
;             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
;         return Prop_ReadWrite;
;         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       xor       eax,eax
       mov       edx,[7FFF81634FC8]
       test      edx,edx
       jle       short M00_L01
M00_L00:
       mov       r8d,eax
       add       r8d,[rcx+10]
       mov       [rcx+10],r8d
       inc       eax
       cmp       eax,edx
       jl        short M00_L00
M00_L01:
       mov       eax,[rcx+10]
       ret
; Total bytes of code 33

-----

.NET 7.0.15 (7.0.1523.57226), X64 RyuJIT AVX2

; Benchmarks.FieldVsProperty.Property_ReadWrite_Write_Add_Separate()
;         for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
;              ^^^^^^^^^
;             var val = Prop_ReadWrite;
;             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
;             Prop_ReadWrite = val + i;
;             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
;         return Prop_ReadWrite;
;         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       xor       eax,eax
       mov       edx,[7FFF81604FC8]
       test      edx,edx
       jle       short M00_L01
M00_L00:
       mov       r8d,[rcx+10]
       add       r8d,eax
       mov       [rcx+10],r8d
       inc       eax
       cmp       eax,edx
       jl        short M00_L00
M00_L01:
       mov       eax,[rcx+10]
       ret
; Total bytes of code 33

-----

.NET 8.0.6 (8.0.624.26715), X64 RyuJIT AVX-512F+CD+BW+DQ+VL+VBMI

; Benchmarks.FieldVsProperty.Property_ReadWrite_Write_Add()
;         for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
;              ^^^^^^^^^
;             Prop_ReadWrite += i;
;             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
;         return Prop_ReadWrite;
;         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       xor       eax,eax
       mov       edx,[7FFF85411C70]
       test      edx,edx
       jle       short M00_L01
M00_L00:
       add       [rcx+10],eax
       inc       eax
       cmp       eax,edx
       jl        short M00_L00
M00_L01:
       mov       eax,[rcx+10]
       ret
; Total bytes of code 25

-----

.NET 8.0.6 (8.0.624.26715), X64 RyuJIT AVX-512F+CD+BW+DQ+VL+VBMI

; Benchmarks.FieldVsProperty.Property_ReadWrite_Write_Add_Separate()
;         for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
;              ^^^^^^^^^
;             var val = Prop_ReadWrite;
;             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
;             Prop_ReadWrite = val + i;
;             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
;         return Prop_ReadWrite;
;         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       xor       eax,eax
       mov       edx,[7FFF85411C70]
       test      edx,edx
       jle       short M00_L01
M00_L00:
       add       [rcx+10],eax
       inc       eax
       cmp       eax,edx
       jl        short M00_L00
M00_L01:
       mov       eax,[rcx+10]
       ret
; Total bytes of code 25


While .NET 8 is identical, the only difference in the .NET 7 disassembly is that Add (the slower of the two) has
mov r8d,eax
add r8d,[rcx+10]

while Add_Separate (the faster) has
mov r8d,[rcx+10]
add r8d,eax

Info
My question is twofold:

Why would this seemingly inconsequential switch of memory locations(?) result in such an insane speed difference?
Is there a known reason that this is the case in .NET 7, but not .NET 8? What changed?

Potentially relevantly, I've run into very strange but similar issues with setting GPU memory via pointer in .NET 7, which is multiple times slower than .NET 8. The details for that deserve their own post, but I do wonder whether .NET 7 is cursed, or if they share a root cause.
For completeness, the benchmarks were performed by Benchmark.NET on:
Windows 10.0.19045.4412/22H2/2022Update
AMD Ryzen 9 7900X
Other Benchmarks
A colleague of mine also ran the benchmark twice with the following results:
| Method                                | Runtime  | Mean       | Error   | StdDev  | Code Size |
|-------------------------------------- |--------- |-----------:|--------:|--------:|----------:|
| Property_ReadWrite_Write_Add          | .NET 7.0 |   284.5 ns | 5.59 ns | 8.19 ns |      33 B |
| Property_ReadWrite_Write_Add_Separate | .NET 7.0 |   256.1 ns | 3.04 ns | 2.54 ns |      33 B |
| Property_ReadWrite_Write_Add          | .NET 8.0 | 1,488.2 ns | 6.57 ns | 5.49 ns |      25 B |
| Property_ReadWrite_Write_Add_Separate | .NET 8.0 | 1,496.4 ns | 7.92 ns | 7.02 ns |      25 B |

Their configuration:
Windows 11 (10.0.22631.4037/23H2/2023Update/SunValley3)
12th Gen Intel Core i9-12900HK
.NET 7.0.16 (7.0.1624.6629), X64 RyuJIT AVX2
.NET 8.0.6 (8.0.624.26715), X64 RyuJIT AVX2
Benchmark Code
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Configs;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Environments;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Jobs;

namespace Benchmarks;

[DisassemblyDiagnoser(maxDepth: 1, printSource:true)]
[Config(typeof(Config))]
public class FieldVsProperty
{
    public int Prop_ReadWrite { get; set; } = Random.Shared.Next();

    public static int N = 1000;
    
    [Benchmark]
    public int Property_ReadWrite_Write_Add()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            Prop_ReadWrite += i;
        }
        return Prop_ReadWrite;
    }
    [Benchmark]
    public int Property_ReadWrite_Write_Add_Separate()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            var val = Prop_ReadWrite;
            Prop_ReadWrite = val + i;
        }
        return Prop_ReadWrite;
    }
    
    private class Config : ManualConfig
    {
        public Config()
        {
            AddJob(Job.Default.WithRuntime(CoreRuntime.Core70));
            AddJob(Job.Default.WithRuntime(CoreRuntime.Core80));
        }
    }
}


Also: it is no secret that .Net 8 has been blessed with numerous performance boosts compared to earlier versions. This may be one of them?

@Fildor .NET 8 is definitely a lot faster in general, but this seems less like a "better optimisation" change and more like a "it really shouldn't be doing that" issue to me. I have wondered if it's replicable on other CPUs, but I don't have the ability to test that.

It's likely wrong to call this a performance degradation, but instead a perf improvement with .NET 8. unless this wasn't present in .NET 6 for example.

If it doesn't break anything and is significantly faster, then I really don't think it is a "shouldn't be doing that" thing. That's pretty unlikely. If anything then a "should have been doing that in the first place" :)

@DavidG The point of the verbiage was more to indicate the performance of += value relative to = local + value, though I see that the mention of .NET versions implies otherwise. It might be pertinent to add that both methods have the same, lower run time when performed on a field.

Oh well, a tenth of a nanosecond is well within the error margin. So, I really didn't think you were talking about that.

@Fildor the difference feels pretty moot, at least from the perspective of "this is probably unintended and definitely undesirable". Either way, I want to know what changed between the versions to result in this improvement and why the difference in assembly code would result in such a vast performance difference. Whether it's a fantastic optimisation or a bug is besides the point.

@Fildor I think there's been a miscommunication. I'm referring to the difference between Add and Add_Separate on .NET 7

Ah, I see. To get that answered, you will probably need to get lucky and summon one of the "insiders".

This is hard to explain.  You're not going to find 1.2 microseconds back by staring at this machine code.  It is about the cost of a soft page fault, entirely normal in a .net program, but the benchmarker is expected to hide that.  A residue of security software
maybe, big if.  One thing to do is change the order of the methods to see if it only affects the first test.

This looks strange, and I cannot reproduce this behavior. Please share the full benchmark code.

@HansPassant I've performed this multiple times with varying orders/included methods with the same result. Would a soft page fault really be consistent across hundreds of thousands of method calls and several different benchmark runs?

@SergejChristoforov that is interesting, but not totally surprising. I've edited the question with the benchmark code

https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/issues/2190

@HansPassant Identical results with or without tiered compilation.

I think you'd have more luck over at dotnet/runtime issues

Which CPU HW are you using? It's possible the differences are attributable to some micro-architectural feature like JCC erratum, and the slightly different code sequences have different encoding sizes, so one version is ok and the other isn't.
